# CORS is preventing me making API calls

Tags: java, spring, cors

I have an application that is running on two docker containers, a frontend(react.js) and a backend(java, spring).

I have the containers up and running and can verify that they can communicate with one another through ping.

After noticing this issue I looked into it and found a question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874351/spring-boot-enabling-cors-by-application-properties) that a user `gok` provided some useful information and a link to the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors) which was very informative.

I have applied the changes to my backend code as I was instructed to do so in an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198743/cant-perform-api-request-from-one-docker-image-to-another) prior to finding out the issue was a CORS one.

So from reading the spring docs I have applied the following to my classes

**Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/blockchain/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://frontend:3000")
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

*Note* I have tried the mapping name of `localhost` and `frontend` (container name), neither worked

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/blockchain")
public class BlockchainController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(value = "/address/create")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getNewAddress() {
        String newAddress = blockchainService.getNewAddress();

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(newAddress)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(newAddress, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

*Note* before asked there's more to the controller class, I only included what was necessary.

**Console Error**

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://multichain-api:8080/api/blockchain/address/create. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

This error was always coming up and has not changed since I included cors config in my app. Also there is no errors showing in the container logs for this.

Any help or insight into this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can u try with this annotation `@Order(SecurityProperties.IGNORED_ORDER)` instead of `@EnableWebMvc` in your `WebConfiguration.class`

Comment: Just tried it and its the same error

Comment: I posted new answer can u check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did before like this , can u try ?  Different from your tried , i added some `exposedHeaders()`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/blockchain/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://frontend:3000")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, " +
                                "Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers")
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

U can remove no need headers which is written in exposeHeaders method. So your problem is with not exposing the `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"`. U can use only this or more.

Comment: So I have tried the `exposeHeaders` with `EnableWebMvc` and `Order(SecurityProperties.IGNORED_ORDER)`, both at separate times and its still the same. I am really puzzled by this as the error on the console is the very same each time and theres no logs in the backend at all

Comment: turns out I was calling the docker container while I should have been calling the localhost. Once I changed this, your proposed solution worked. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in my local.

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://frontend:3000")
    @GetMapping(value = "/address/create")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getNewAddress() {
      ...}
```

Comment: Bad idea, i think. Base url or port info are in the properties or config file. So if u change config file , u have to change this CrossOrigin mapping. So not a good option.

Comment: I agree, just an option for localhost testing.

Comment: Like a developpers lie,  "It works in my Local" :) just joking mate

Comment: This was one of the first things I tried and it didn't work for me unfortunately