# CORS request failing in docker-compose environment

Tags: reactjs, flask, cors

I'm hoping to figure out why an API request in a React application running in Firefox is failing.

Headers are as follows:

```
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
DNT 1
Host    backend:8080
origin  http://localhost:3000
Referer http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 ...
```

On Chrome, an opaque message tells of some sort of network(ish) error:

```
request.js?176a:41 GET http://backend:8080/api/foobar/ 
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

On Firefox, there seems to be a bit more info:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://backend:8080/api/foobar/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

---

I have a environment composed of two relevant nodes, `frontend` and `backend`. `frontend` is running a server hosting the React `frontend` bits. `backend` is a Flask app providing a set of simple JSON APIs. The intent is for `frontend` to call `backend` via JSON APIs.

The `docker-compose` config is such that they're running on the same logical network. At first, I had suspected the issue was a `docker-compose` issue, and maybe some DNS mishap. However, I was able to exclude this case by manually stopping the `frontend` node, and manually re-attaching the same container to the network so I could run a `bash` shell and ping the `backend` host. Furthermore, I was able to fetch the same bits via `curl` from the `backend`. So this excludes it being a Docker networking issue (I think).

The next logical culprit is something to do with CORS. The `frontend` request is hitting a distinct domain, (e.g. `backend`) so this could explain the behavior.

Following the [docs listed in the dev console of Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed) the claim is a "fundamental network error of some kind" occurred.

For good measure, I set up [Flask-CORS](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on the `backend` and verified the right headers are being relayed from the server. To be precise, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Yet, from the logs of the `backend` server - there are still no new network requests being made. I had speculated that maybe there was an `OPTION` request being fired at the `backend` per the special case described in the [Mozilla CORS Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), and that was failing. Yet that would at least have triggered a log entry in the Flask console output indicating an `OPTION` request was fired. To indulge my paranoia I even broke out Wireshark. There doesn't even appear to be any relevant network requests being emitted from Firefox (nor Chrome) !

Odds are I am over complicating this, and it's something painfully simple.  But would love some pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

TLDR - JavaScript runs in the browser (says the backend dev)

The host referred on the `frontend` should be `localhost` as the `backend` port is exposed on `localhost` via Docker. And the `frontend` code is running in the browser (as opposed to exclusively in the container). The container was just a process serving up those bits.

The opaque network error was likely a result of referring to a domain name that didn't exist to the host network. Because it was part of the `docker-compose` virtual network.